# Multiple field pass to get the query failed

Tags: node.js, mongodb, sails.js, sails-mongo

I am trying to find the list of users based on the different queries. Like if I pass `firstname` or `lastname` or `location` I want data based on one of them or all of them but I've failed to get the details. And also there are 2 nested fields I want to pass for the check. These are here `"otherDetails.nationality": "Indian"` and `"professionalDetails.type": "Cook"`. Whenever I pass them a single query check I get the desired data but Whenever I put all of them in the `$or` aggregation method it fails and gives me all the data in database. I was stuck here for 2 days and couldn't solve it. A help will be appreciated

here is a glimpse of the database data. Don't go with the same its one record I copied multiple times and I also removed some of the fields I make it clean

```
[{
        "_id": "604670a613a06f0017702d88",
        "firstname": "Babulal ",
        "lastname": "Gadri",
        "mobile": "00000000000",
        "otherDetails": {
            "nationality": "Indian"
        },
        "professionalDetails": {
            "type": "Cook"
        }
}

{
        "_id": "604670a613a06f0017702d8a",
        "firstname": "Babulal ",
        "lastname": "Gadri",
        "mobile": "00000000000",
        "otherDetails": {
            "nationality": "Indian"
        },
        "professionalDetails": {
            "type": "Cook"
        }
}
{
        "_id": "604670a613a06f0017702d8b",
        "firstname": "Babulal ",
        "lastname": "Gadri",
        "mobile": "00000000000",
        "otherDetails": {
            "nationality": "Indian"
        },
        "professionalDetails": {
            "type": "Cook"
        }
}
{
        "_id": "604670a613a06f0017702d88",
        "firstname": "Babulal ",
        "lastname": "Gadri",
        "mobile": "00000000000",
        "otherDetails": {
            "nationality": "Indian"
        },
        "professionalDetails": {
            "type": "Cook"
        }
}
{
        "_id": "604670a613a06f0017702d8c",
        "firstname": "Babulal ",
        "lastname": "Gadri",
        "mobile": "00000000000",
        "otherDetails": {
            "nationality": "Indian"
        },
        "professionalDetails": {
            "type": "Chef"
        }
}

]
```

Here is the function I am doing

```
searchCookForNotification: async function (req, res) {
    let { type, nationality, firstname, lastname, location } = req.query;

    var db = Person.getDatastore().manager;

    var cooks = await db
      .collection(Person.tableName)
      .find({
        $or: [
          { firstname },
          { lastname },
          { location },
          { "professionalDetails.type": type },
          { "otherDetails.nationality": nationality },
        ],
      })
      .toArray();

    console.log("Length: ", cooks.length);

    return res.successResponse(
      cooks,
      200,
      null,
      true,
      "Cooks found successfully"
    );
  },
};
```

Comment: Please give an example request, together with the expected and the observed result.

Comment: @HeikoTheißen the result is all data in my database I am getting But I can tell you some of my fields has different types and different nationality But I am getting all of them I checked multiple times an confirmed with length

Comment: @Martinez Can you help me with this

Comment: Are you sure you want `"$or"` rather than `"$and"`?  I.e., do you want the set union of all the query parameters, or do you want the set intersection of all the query parameters?

Comment: @rickhg12hs I want $or if one of argument show result according to them if the all argument pass result will according to them

Comment: @rickhg12hs its like the more argument come the more result will be specfic

Comment: I'm pretty sure you don't want `"$or"` then - it will return _less_ specific results, i.e., more results (in general).

Comment: Rather than `{ firstname }`, do you need `{"firstname": firstname }`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249910/discussion-between-developer-nans-and-rickhg12hs).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just happening because the code itself is unstable, if one of the parameters does not exist in "query" for example "location" is missing then the condition you create inside the `$or` query will this following query:

```
{ location: undefined }
```

Which from the sample you gave is matches all documents. I imagine you just want to build the query dynamically based on given input:

```
let { type, nationality, firstname, lastname, location } = req.query;
var db = Person.getDatastore().manager;

const orCondArray = [];
if (firstname) {
    orCondArray.push({ firstname })
}
if (lastname) {
    orCondArray.push({ lastname })
}
if (location) {
    orCondArray.push({ location })
}
if (type) {
    orCondArray.push({ "professionalDetails.type": type })
}
if (nationality) {
    orCondArray.push({ "otherDetails.nationality": nationality })
}

if (orCondArray.length) {
  var cooks = await db
    .collection(Person.tableName)
    .find({$or: orCondArray})
    .toArray();
}
```

Comment: Thanks Bro, I am stuck here almost 2 days couldn't figure out It relly help me and new thing I just learn